# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 NOT NULL constraint failed

Tags: php, database, laravel, sqlite, phpunit

I am writing a test in Laravel to create a pin. When I create a pin, I want to save the link to it's own database table. Here is the test:

```
/** @test */
function an_authorized_user_can_create_a_pin()
{
    $this->withoutExceptionHandling();
    $user = create(User::class);
    $this->be($user);

    $pin = make(Pin::class);

    $response = $this->post('/pin', $pin->toArray());

    $this->assertDatabaseHas('pins', [
        'user_id' => $user->id,
        'title' => $pin->title,
    ])
    ->assertDatabaseHas('links', [
        'link' => $pin->link,
        'pin_id' => $createdPin->id
    ]);
}
```

The test is failing with this error:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity 
constraint violation: 19 NOT NULL constraint failed: links.link (SQL: 
insert into "links" ("link", "pin_id", "updated_at", "created_at") 
values (, 1, 2018-08-20 21:44:19, 2018-08-20 21:44:19))
```

This is my controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $pin = new Pin();
    $pin->user_id = auth()->id();
    $pin->title = $request->title;
    $pin->save();

    $pinLink = new Link();
    $pinLink->link = $request->link;
    $pinLink->pin_id = $pin->id;
    $pinLink->save();
}
```

Here is the factories for both:

```
<?php

use App\Pin;
use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->define(Pin::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'user_id' => function () {
            return factory('App\User')->create()->id;
        },
        'title' => $faker->sentence(20),
    ];
});
```

and

```
<?php

use App\Pin;
use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->define(Pin::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'user_id' => function () {
            return factory('App\User')->create()->id;
        },
        'title' => $faker->sentence(20),
    ];
});
```

This is where i'm not quite sure what to do as I am fairly new to PHP and Laravel (amd maybe everything around like Mysql / PDO, eager to learn).

Comment: Sounds like there is a relation in the database that is not satisfied by just inserting a pin. Might be the relation is too strict but also might be that the pin is not valid to insert. This heavily depends on your database schema, who created the schema? Why is there this NOT NULL constraint? Who is the DBA of that project, if at all there is any, just asking.

Comment: I created the database schema

Comment: Would you say the constraint is what you want it to be?

Comment: I don’t think so. Where link is getting inserted as null, I want that to be the link I give when I create a pin.

Comment: So if NULL is OK for the constraint, allow it. It's less a problem with the test then but you just found out the database definition had a problem (which is nice to find our through tests as you define in those what should work (and what should not)) -> fix the data definition.

Comment: Ok thanks! I’m not quite sure what fixing the data definition means?

Comment: Think of it that the application is bound to the databse. So the database comes first. There are two parts in the databse, the structure and the actual  data. The data definition actually defines the structure the data must fit in. If you don't allow NULL on a field for example by the databases structure, you can wnat to enter any data you want, but if contains NULL. just not allowed unless you allow that.

Comment: Ok so I need to change the way the data fits into the database?

Comment: Yes, that is a true sentence, for both parts: changing the data and/or changing the database. Depending on what you want to control.